# d3.js get JSON from url

Tags: javascript, json, azure, d3.js

The situation is that i am trying to get d3 to read a JSON file which is stored in Windows Azure Blob storage. If i paste the url into a browser then the file is downloaded to my machine. I would like to be able get the JSON file from the url with d3, but no graph is produced which leads me to believe that the d3 is unable to read the file.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
            var url = "http://storageName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/file.json";

            d3.json("url", function (json) {

             //code here
            })
```

I have set the container to public on Azure, so i believe that it should be accessible to anyone with the url. Any suggestions?

Comment: i'm getting the following error accessing the url : 

`One of the request inputs is out of range. RequestId:9bddf99a-7459-4eba-a962-bd85452442d8 Time:2014-03-11T12:56:47.5460693Z`

Is this the right url?

Comment: no this is not the correct url! i cannot share the url here for obvious reasons!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when running the code?

Comment: yes Lars, i am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://storage.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50332' is therefore not allowed access. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to set the Content-Type http header to "application/json" on your blob.

It can be done programmatically or using the rest API, or using a free utility like cloudberry explorer for azure blob storage.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When you say set the content type, can i do this on the server side when i am creating the blob?or does this have to be done client side?

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, after doing what you mentioned and setting the AllowedOrigins to * i can now work with the JSON file

Answer (score 15):

Should be:

```
var url = "http://storageName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/file.json";
d3.json(url, function (json) {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: This would run in a CORS violation.

Answer (score 6):

Relevant for 2019:

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:8080/mydata.json").then( data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For REST api use d3.request:

```
d3.fetch("api_url/path")
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.post(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: From d3 V5, d3.request is deprecated. Use d3.fetch instead.