# us.json file not loading for choropleth

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

The first `console.log` in this code block throws **"Syntax error: Unexpected token <"**, and the second and third console.log both throw `undefined`.

The rawgit link works perfectly... why isn't it loading the json?

```
// Begin queue
queue()

  // Load map JSON
  .defer(d3.json, 'http://rawgit.com/HyperrealTech/thorn-directives/master/lib/us.json')

  // Load applicable data
  .defer(d3.json, data)

  // Once finished loading, call ready function
  .await(ready);

// Ready function
function ready(error, us, data) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(us);
  console.log(data);
  data.forEach(function(d) { 
    rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
  });
```

Comment: did you lint the json?

Comment: No, it's taking right from Mike's block... didn't think I had to.

Comment: Not really sure. But try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325819/d3-js-get-json-from-url The exterior url may be throwing the error.

Comment: Shit... how do I set a content header type here...

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/> Worth a shot. You should host the file on your server, though.

Comment: Do I just add that to the us.json file?

Comment: no to your .html file head. I am just guessing here, by the way. Accessing external files is tricky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57128/discussion-between-zelliott-and-in-code-veritas).