# How to pass data to d3.json()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Currently the code is working perfect. It's just that I want a different tree chart for each user. So I have to pass $user in getData.php so that the json data get created according to this user and then the chart. $user is used in mysql select statements in getData.php to select data from database and this selected data is then converted into json.

Please tell me how do I pass $user as a callback in which d3 function. I am out of my resources!!

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
var url = "d3js/getData.php" + queryString;
d3.json(url, function(error, treeData) {
    console.log(treeData)
    root = treeData[0];
    update(root);
});
```

At the end of the getData.php there is

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($tree);
```

So I guess the output of the php file is json data

Comment: What is the structure of your getData.php ?

Comment: It's a tree structure.

Comment: Is it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150668/json-schema-for-tree-structure ?

Comment: Yes it is something like that.

Comment: is treeData being logged to the console? and is it properly encoded json? Have you tried going to the url: http://domain/d3js/getData.php+query and seeing the output of the file.

Comment: Yes, when I go to http://localhost/root8/d3js/getData.php I see the json data like  [{....},{....},......,{.....}]

Answer (score 1):

`d3.json` function is used to get the data from a json file which doesn't work for PHP files which returns response other than json format.

You can use d3-request API. On call back - you can render your graph:
Example:

```
var url = "d3js/getData.php" + window.location.search;
d3.request(url)
.get(function(error, treeData) {
   console.log(treeData)
   root = treeData[0];
   update(root);
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request

For more details - https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md

Comment: 1. In your call back function, you can parse your json data.
2. Based on the request type, you have to call appropriate request method(post, get...)

Comment: If the PHP file is returning JSON encoded data, then d3.json can call a php file. Works for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
d3.json("api.php", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
   loop your datas;
});
```

For more look here

https://phpro.org/tutorials/Creating-Graphs-With-PHP-MySQL-D3JS.html

https://nyquist212.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/d3-js-live-dashboard-example/

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html

Comment: Thats the syntax, if you have working url then you have to put the absolute url in that place

Answer (score 0):

For a start you need to export your data to a json file such as data.json

d3.json() will expect a json file not a php file.

```
 d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
      ...
});
```

Comment: I still think it needs to be a json file that you call. Check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325819/d3-js-get-json-from-url

Comment: My code works fine. Currently I provide $user=1; in getData.php which contains mysql code as well to fetch data. But since my data would be according to the user I have to pass the user data to getData.php

Comment: I understand your query gets you json but does it get a json file?

Comment: Yes it is something like that. At the end of getData.php these are the commands: header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($tree);

Answer (score 0):

The code I use is:

```
function upL(l_id) {
d3.json("lsel.php?l_id=" + l_id, function(error, gr) {
     if (error) {
        return console.error(error)
    } else
        console.log(gr);
        draw(gr)
}).header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")//this bit might be necessary
}

function draw(gr){create graph...}
```

(l_id is a user selected variable)

So yours looks OK, try adding the content-type (.header(...)) and if treeData is being logged to the console, the problem might be the way you're accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function to get map your values:

```
 d3.layout.stack()(['value'].map((value) => {
  return data.map((d: any) => {
    return { x: obj[d.xAxis], y: d.value };
  });
}));
```

You can also see more example here-

https://github.com/amanjain325/angular-d3-charts